# .NET hide titlebar but keep border

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I was wondering how to hide the titlebar of a form but keep the original border, like e.g Dropbox does:
[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set `FormBorderStyle` to `FormBorderStyle.Sizable` or `FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow` and set `Text` to an empty string, and `ControlBox` to `false`

Note that `FixedToolWindow` won't work, it will remove the border. If you don't want it to be sizable, use `SizableToolWindow` and add this to the form's codebehind (adding both languages since you don't specify and tagged the question with both):

In vb.net:

```vb
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef message As Message)               
    If message.Msg = &H84 Then ' WM_NCHITTEST
        message.Result = CType(1, IntPtr)
        Return
    End If    
    MyBase.WndProc(message)
End Sub
```

In C#:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
{
    if (message.Msg == 0x0084) // WM_NCHITTEST
        message.Result = (IntPtr)1;   
    else base.WndProc(ref message);
}
```

Comment: This hides the border of the form completely. It's the same as setting `FormBorderStyle` to `FormBorderStyle.None`.

Comment: @Brennced no, it doesn't, I just made a test, and it shows the border, exactly like Dropbox's window

Comment: Nevermind. I forgot to remove some code that hides the form border. Thank you for your quick answer.

Comment: Amazing! I've been wanting this too!

Comment: @HansPassant good catch. I see you did update already. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way:

```
this.ControlBox = false;
this.Text = string.Empty;
```

If the Form is designed to be a pop-up dialog, you might want to add the following line:

```
this.ShowInTaskBar = false;
```

That keeps the Form from appearing in the taskbar.

Answer (score -1):

```
// 3rd option (C#)
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        int WS_DLGFRAME = 0x400000;
        CreateParams result = base.CreateParams;
        result.Style &= ~WS_DLGFRAME;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @IgorF. As it says, it's a 3rd option. Period. I was googling with the memory that there is a property one could override and change window creation, but I couldn't find it here. Of course I prefer Smith's answer. Last thing I would do in such a case is override `WndProc`.