# Trap WM_NCHITTEST message but keep checking for MouseEnter/-Leave

Tags: vb.net, winforms, wndproc, window-messages

I've got a form where I've removed the title bar but kept the border (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35114141/3740093)).

In the above answer it's stated that it's required to have the `FormBorderStyle` set to `Sizable` or `SizableToolWindow`, and in order to stop the form from being sizable you'd trap the WM_NCHITTEST event. The only problem being that doing so will make it *not* raise the normal `Form_MouseEnter` or `Form_MouseLeave` events.

Is there any workaround to this?

My code:

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef message As Message)
    If message.Msg = &H84 Then 'WM_NCHITTEST
        Me.Focus() 'Focus the form when it receives a click.
        Return
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(message)
End Sub

Private Sub PanelForm_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PanelForm.MouseLeave
    PlaceOnScreen(False) 'Placed a breakpoint here, it won't execute.
End Sub
```

Comment: Why a sudden downvote after all this time? Anyone care to elaborate or is it just a hater who's got nothing better to do?

Comment: Both question and answer are useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a bug, the return value of WM_NCHITTEST is right now 0.  Which means "the mouse is nowhere".  So lots of stuff stops working, like activating and focusing the window and the MouseEnter event.  You must return 1 (aka HTCLIENT) instead, means "it is on the client area":

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef message As Message)
    If message.Msg = &H84 Then 'WM_NCHITTEST
        message.Result = CType(1, IntPtr)
        Return
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(message)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried many different workarounds without any success.