# Remove title bar while keeping border

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'd like to create a Form without title bar while keeping the border so I can still resize and snap it. Setting `FormBorderStyle` to `None` would work, but it destroys the border.

After searching Google for a bit, I encountered a method quite a few times, also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35114141/4632495): Setting `ControlBox` to `False` as well as `Text` to an empty string seems to have worked on older versions of Windows, on Windows 10 however it looks like this:

[image: Ugly rest of title bar]

Note the ugly bar at the top, which I would like to get rid of. Every other solution I found - e.g. overriding WndProc - either simply did not work, or removed the border as well.

***Edit:*** The white bar is in non-client area, it's what's left over from the title bar after removing the window buttons and title text.

Comment: Can confirm that. Ugly white non-client bar on top. It's acting as a border, to resize the height, why is it so big? Must be a bug.

Comment: Would you mind to try [this hack](https://superuser.com/a/961865/547545), perhaps it's mentioned `PaddedBorderWidth`.

Comment: On this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575216/how-to-move-and-resize-a-form-without-a-border the second answer by user1306322 uses `FormBorderStyle=None` but draws the border back on and handles the necessary events to allow it to be resizable.

Comment: @Sinatr As far as I can tell, this modifies the registry, which is a global approach to this problem. However, I'd like my application to work on any Windows machine, without having to change the registry.

Comment: @steve16351 I've already stumbled across that answer, but my application still does not support resizing or snapping after using the code.

Comment: [Prevent Win32 from drawing classic title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46776425/prevent-win32-from-drawing-classic-title-bar). Not a *final* answer, but you can work with it. See the Docs [DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmextendframeintoclientarea) and [DwmSetWindowAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmsetwindowattribute). You can find most of the declaration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51580871/7444103).

Comment: See also: [Custom Window Frame Using DWM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dwm/customframe) and this CodeProject: [Fancy Windows Forms](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/33716/fancy-windows-forms?fid=1536616&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&fr=101). Different paths.

Comment: Benni did you found a way to solve the problema with the ugly bar at top?

Comment: @Xam unfortunately, I did not :(

Answer (score 1):

I only manged to do it with WndProc.
But no bar at the top. Can be moved. Can be snap.
WM_NCHITTEST is for resiz window.
WM_NCCALCSIZE Is for removing the "ugly white line".

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var designSize = this.ClientSize;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
        this.Size = designSize;
        
    }
    
const int WM_NCCALCSIZE = 0x83;
const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
{
if (message.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST && message.Result == (IntPtr)0)
{
    int GrabSize = 30;
    int x = unchecked((short)(long)message.LParam);
    int y = unchecked((short)((long)message.LParam >> 16));
    var rect2 = new Rectangle(DesktopLocation.X + GrabSize, DesktopLocation.Y + GrabSize, ClientSize.Width - (GrabSize*2), ClientSize.Height - (GrabSize * 2));
    if (!rect2.Contains(x, y))
    {
        if (y > rect2.Bottom && x < rect2.Left)
        {
            message.Result = (IntPtr)16;// # HTBOTTOMLEFT
        }
        else if (y < rect2.Top && x > rect2.Right)
        {
            message.Result = (IntPtr)14;// # HTTOPRIGHT
        }
        else if (y > rect2.Bottom && x > rect2.Right)
        {
            message.Result = (IntPtr)17;// # HTBOTTOMRIGHT 
        }
        else if (y < rect2.Top && x < rect2.Left)
        {
            message.Result = (IntPtr)13;// # HTTOPLEFT 
        }
        else if (y > rect2.Bottom)
        {
            message.Result = (IntPtr)15; //# HTBOTTOM
        }
        else if (y < rect2.Top)
        {
            message.Result = (IntPtr)2; //# HTCAPTION for moving the window
            //message.Result = (IntPtr)12; //# HTTOP
        }
        else if (x < rect2.Left)
        {
            message.Result = (IntPtr)10; //# HTLEFT
        }
        else if (x > rect2.Right)
        {
            message.Result = (IntPtr)11;//# HTRIGHT
        }

    }
    else
    {

        message.Result = (IntPtr)(1); // # HTCLIENT In a client area.
        
    }
    return;
}    
if (message.Msg == WM_NCCALCSIZE && message.WParam.ToInt32() == 1)
{
    message.Result = (IntPtr)0; 
    return;
}
base.WndProc(ref message);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set BorderStyle to bsNone

then in the form's OnActivate, procedure, add the lines

```
 Canvas.Pen.Color:=clWindowFrame;
 
 Canvas.Rectangle(0,0,Width-2,Height-2)
```

Comment: What is `Canvas`?

Comment: Canvas is a property, in this case, of your form. Look up TCanvas in Delphi help: "TCanvas provides an abstract drawing space for objects that must render their own images. "

Comment: ..or C#. https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Athens/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas

Comment: What relation does Delphi have to C# and WinForms?

Comment: If you Google WinForms, you should find the answer. Personally, I'm not a Visual Studio user.

Comment: I looked a little further and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64545678/c-sharp-windows-form-line-wont-draw-canvas-is-not-defined. TCanvas has been in Borland/Embarcadero products for almost forever. However, there is a discussion in this link that indicates you can use a graphic called canvas to draw on. Maybe what you need. Sorry about the confusion - context lacking!

Comment: `TCanvas has been in Borland/Embarcadero products for almost forever` - and yet this question is about C# and Winforms that have nothing to do with Borland/Embarcadero and never had `Canvas`. The context is not lacking, the question is tagger C# and Winforms.

Comment: The quotation above is about C# and .NET so should be relevant. I looked at  the top of the page for the context where I would normally expect a headiing.