# C# windows form, Line wont Draw! canvas is not defined

Tags: c#, windows, forms, line, draw

What is needed to define 'canvas' on line 27? I've looked everywhere but it only gives respoenses of why an object might not be defined, and not about why the specific object canvas is not defined. Can someone tell me what i'm Missing?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void canvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics gObject = canvas.CreateGraphics();

            Brush red = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            Pen redPen = new Pen(red, 8);

            gObject.DrawLine(redPen, 10, 10, 35, 500);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Can someone tell me what i'm Missing?"* An object named canvas maybe?

Comment: Also, and no less important you __need__ to replace `Graphics gObject = canvas.CreateGraphics();` with `Graphics gObject = e.Graphics;` - Winforms graphics basic rule #1 : 

Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..


You can test the persistance of your graphics by doing a Minimize/Maximize sequence..

Comment: Also: Where did you find that piece of code? (It has errors on almost each line!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `canvas` must be a control in the form. You got to add it in the designer and give it the `canvas` name. What kind? Hmm… I'd say use a PictureBox.

You would also need to link the `Paint` event to `canvas_Paint` from the properties panel (events tab). And yes, `e.Graphics` is preferred over using `CreateGraphics`.

*Where did you get that code from?*

Comment: The same code was actually from multiple places, but I got it from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s94WCTDMtbw.

Comment: @scarreer There, first shot of the video, you can see in the properties panel that the selected item is a `Panel` named `canvas` with the `Paint` event linked to `canvas_Paint`. And, looking at the designer, I guess it is had `Dock` set to `Fill` and `BackColor` to `White`. That should get you started.

Comment: @scarreer The author should not be using `CreateGraphics`. It is leaking them, to begin with. Just use `e.Graphics`.

Comment: You should also be disposing of the Brush and Pen that was created.

Comment: PictureBox would be a better canvas than Panel as it is DoubleBuffered out of the box.