Why does maximizing a frameless form cause the MaximizedBounds to change?
I have a WinForms app that needs to have a custom titlebar, so I removed the native titlebar via FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
This causes an issue where the maximized window covers the taskbar. This is mentioned in a couple other posts like this one.
The answer with the most upvotes suggests: this.MaximizedBounds = Screen.FromHandle(this.Handle).WorkingArea;, but that doesn't quite work for me, because the window is like half off screen.
The solution below works better:
var workingArea = Screen.FromHandle(Handle).WorkingArea;
MaximizedBounds =  new Rectangle(0, 0, workingArea.Width, workingArea.Height);

On my primary monitor, it maximizes fine. On my secondary monitor, the right and bottom sides go off screen. (to be clear, the first time it launches on the secondary monitor, it launches fine. It's that when I unmaximize and maximize again, it goes off screen; DPI is 100% on both monitors)
I added a MaximizedBoundsChanged event handler which is showing that when I maximize the Form form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized, the form's MaximizedBounds is getting changed for some reason:
So I set the MaximizedBounds to {X=0,Y=0,Width=2560,Height=1392} which then gets changed to {X=1920,Y=-99,Width=3200,Height=1460}
(interestingly enough, 3200 - 2560 = 640 and 2560 (width of secondary monitor) - 640 = 1920 (width of primary monitor).
My code is like this:
var workingArea = Screen.FromHandle(this.Handle).WorkingArea;
var maximizedBounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, workingArea.Width, workingArea.Height);
MaximizedBounds = maximizedBounds;
ResizeEnd += (s, e) =>
{
    var workingArea = Screen.FromHandle(this.Handle).WorkingArea;
    var maximizedBounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, workingArea.Width, workingArea.Height);
    MaximizedBounds = maximizedBounds;
};

I looked at the solution here and set dpi awareness to PerMonitorV2 in app.manifest as well as by calling this in my Main method: Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.PerMonitorV2);
No help.
Why does maximizing the Form change the MaximizedBounds? What's triggering that? This doesn't happen when I add the titlebar back (remove FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None)
I just want a frameless Form that doesn't cover the taskbar when maximized.

It's not clear what .NET version you're targeting. Add the missing information -- If you can call this: Application.SetHighDpiMode(), it's assumed that you're not targeting .NET Framework, so the app.manifest thing is counter-productive. You should post the code that calls SetHighDpiMode(), since .NET 7+ already does that, based on the <ApplicationHighDpiMode> setting in the .csproj file, when calling the automatic ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize() method

added tag; targeting .net 8. Are you just saying that the app.manifest file is redundant since I can call the SetHighDpiMode directly? ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize() is calling Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);. After I make that Initialize call, I call Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.PerMonitorV2); @Jimi

First thing, remove anything DpiAwarenes-related you have added to the app.manifest, except the part where you specify (uncommenting) the System versions you support (mandatory). Then, add to the starting Project's .csproj file, in the main <PropertyGroup> (where the .exe type is specified), <ApplicationHighDpiMode>PerMonitorV2</ApplicationHighDpiMode>. Now ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize() sets PerMonitorV2 correctly. Then read the stuff here: Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors

@Jimi Thanks - will read that. Though I just added <ApplicationHighDpiMode>PerMonitorV2</ApplicationHighDpiMode> to the exe's csproj and Initialize still configures DPI mode with SystemAware. Maybe I need to force a regeneration of that file somehow

@Jimi nevermind, restarted VS and it shows up correctly now

@Jimi well, I read it though, not clear how that helps me in this case. Both my monitors are at 100% DPI, so I'm not even sure this is DPI related. I'm trying to figure out why maximizing the form changes its MaximizedBounds

That was for setting the DpiAwaress straight (and you didn't mention the scale of the monitors), and to introduce the VirtualScreen. Now, in OnShown, add Location = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Location; formDefaultSize = ClientSize;, where formDefaultSize is a Field used to store the normal size of the Form. The Form should be placed at the upper-left corner of the secondary screen. After that, just set: var screen = Screen.FromHandle(this.Handle); ClientSize = screen.WorkingArea.Size; -- This assumes that StartPosition = Manual and you're scaling the Form to Dpi

↑ Reposted because WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized; has been pasted in by mistake

@pushkin, I edited my answer. You can also try the second solution.

@Pushkin, did you try solutions 2 and 3 that I suggested a few days ago? Did not solve the problem? In the test I had done, solution 2 was fine on my laptop.

One thing that some programmers do for the border of the form is to choose a jpeg image as the background image of the form, and that image is the background with the desired color or image plus a beautiful and artistic border. Even the four corners for the border of the form can be curved with this method (of course, if the form is transparent and borderless).

@BabakM. that doesn't quite work for me. I figured out some other way to do this which I will post sometime later.

You could remove the title bar in WndProc like this:
const int WM_NCCALCSIZE = 0x83;
protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
{
    
    if (message.Msg == WM_NCCALCSIZE && message.WParam.ToInt32() == 1)
    {
        message.Result = (IntPtr)0;
        return;
    }
    base.WndProc(ref message);
}

The FormBorderStyle can be anything. If it set to None then the whole monitor is filled in Maximized.
If the FormBorderStyle is Sizable then the form will have the property of the Sizable but without the title bar.
If you want to resize the Form or snap to the sides then you can have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78042974/6843577

Thanks - this gets me closer. Aerosnap works and I can maximize the form properly (though it's a tad off; the titlebar when maximized is a little above the screen so it appears smaller; will investigate that). But I tried the linked solution for adding resize capabilities, and that doesn't seem to do anything. I don't get any resize cursor when moving my cursor to the edges

WM_NCHITTEST seems to never "fire"

oh I'm guessing because I have a WebView2 control covering the entire Form. I need to create some space/border for the Form

@pushkin WebView2 definitely captures the WM_NCHITTEST. The "the titlebar when maximized is a little above the screen so it appears smaller" solution: Set the Form ControlBox to Flase. then Form Text to empty string. should solved the problem.

didn't help. Titlebar is still too small when maximized. I put breakpoints in WndProc and it doesn't get hit for WM_NCHITTEST. If I remove the NCCALCSIZE workaround though, they do get hit.

then i am out of options. For me it is working but i work with blank form maybe that could be the different. I don't know.

Solution 1:
If you set "WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized" at design time, the form will not cover the taskbar, but if it is applied at runtime, the form will cover the entire monitor, probably because when maximizing the form, the taskbar temporarily hides.
In any case, I think the following code will solve your problem in WinForm .NET 6:
 FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
 ShowInTaskbar = false;
 WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
 ShowInTaskbar = true;


Solution 2:
You can also override "WndProc" method in form (although this is not ideal):
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    const int WM_SIZE = 0x0005;
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    if (m.Msg == WM_SIZE)
        MaximizedBounds = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea;
}

If we place a desired control in the "Title Bar" area (top of the form in borderless mode), for example a "Panel", we can process the user's double-click on the "Title Bar" to exit the full screen, similar to the following method:
private void panel1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
    {
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
        panel1.Hide();
    }
}


Solution 3:
Also instead of setting WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized, you can use the following code:
protected Rectangle OriginalFormBounds = Rectangle.Empty;
protected FormBorderStyle OriginalFormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
protected void MaximizeForm()
{
    if (FormBorderStyle != FormBorderStyle.None)
    {
        OriginalFormBounds = Bounds;
        OriginalFormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle;
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        Bounds = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea;
    }
}
protected void RestoreFormToNormalSize()
{
    if ((OriginalFormBorderStyle != FormBorderStyle.None) && (OriginalFormBounds != Rectangle.Empty))
    {
        FormBorderStyle = OriginalFormBorderStyle;
        Bounds = OriginalFormBounds;
    }
}
protected void ToggleFormMaximize()
{
    if (FormBorderStyle != FormBorderStyle.None)
        MaximizeForm();
    else
        RestoreFormToNormalSize();
}


I need to support setting maximized at runtime since the user might be maximizing the window. I will try out your solution later to see if it avoids changing the MaximizedBounds

@pushkin, OK, As you see fit. I tested in Visual Studio 2022 with .NET 6 on Windows 11 and it worked on the secondary monitor that was connected to the laptop and worked alone (the 15-inch laptop monitor was off and the 24-inch monitor was displaying the image). In any case, as you said, you should test yourself for what you expect

I checked with the following command, the output was "1048 - 1080".
MessageBox.Show(Height.ToString() + " - " + Screen.FromControl(this).Bounds.Height.ToString());

You know, this does work better. I don't totally get why removing from taskbar helps though. But in any case, there's an annoying flash that happens when you do this that I'm trying to avoid.

though this doesn't work when double clicking on the custom titlebar since it doesn't go through my code apparently and just maximizes

@pushkin, I think the reason why changing the display of the program name in the taskbar helps to prevent the form from covering the taskbar in full screen mode, is that in order to make this change, Windows is forced to display the taskbar when the maximize command is executed. It should be noted that the flash did not occur in the test I did. Most likely, the test conditions for me and you are a little different.

@pushkin, In any case, I don't think that such questions, which are actually fixing Windows or .NET bugs, have accurate and complete answers. Because it refers to issues not documented by Microsoft and it is not clear that it will work in the next versions of Windows and .NET, but if we want to solve it more completely, we should probably change the methods like "Control.WndProc(Message)" or "OnPaint".

A simple implementation of the "WndProc" method would be something like the one I added in my post.
